# Power button does not work unless I short power pin to ground (then the power button works normally afterward)

Tags: switches

The title might be confusing but I am confused as well, This is an old sony ta-808m amplifier.
initially, the issue was a broken power button I have replaced it with a new power button and I can confirm that the power button itself is working (continuity mode using a tester, not by powering on the circuit. Even with the circuit powered on it does work, shorting pin 5 pwr to ground BUT IT STILL DOESNT WANT TO TURN ON) it's just idling in standby mode.

Now my main issue is this I've tested every resistor, transistor, capacitors, and connection paths. All are in the right value.
the only way this amp powers on properly is by using a piece of metal (or any wire) to jump pin 5 to ground. After doing that everything works flawlessly and as intended (and makes the power button work properly as well as if there is no issue.)

the problem goes back when you unplug the amplifier.
you will need to short pin 5 to ground again manually in order to make everything work properly again.

Edit: I even tried replacing the old wires with new ones and it's still the same.

Did I miss something in the circuit that the amplifier won't work (the power button) after unplugging it and plugging it again?
[image]

Comment: Try a cap across switch

Comment: Have you checked the voltages as shown on the schematic?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes all of them are the same as stated in the schematic

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Will try this next

Comment: Are you saying that if you short the switch terminals with some wire it works after a power cycle, but not using the switch?

Comment: @HandyHowie no, in order for it to work I need to short the pin 5 (power/led pin) from the ic itself to ground then it will open. After that, the main power button will work fine (can open the amplifier and close it without any problems) although if I unplug the amp from mains power then plug it back in again the same issue comes back again.

Comment: Clarification please: what does it mean to "open" or "close" the amplifier? I'm assuming that you mean to switch it on or off, but it's not entirely clear which is which. Using terms like "open" and "close" in this context is unusual...

Comment: You say that you need to connect pin 5 to ground, but the other side of the switch is connected to ground according to the schematic.  Have you checked it’s resistance to ground (I found the full schematic on the web)

Comment: @brhans in order for it to work I need to short the pin 5 (power/led pin) from the ic itself to ground then it will Turn on. After that, the main power button will work fine (can turn on the amplifier and shut it down without any problems) although if I unplug the amp from mains power then plug it back in again the same issue comes back again

Comment: @HandyHowie yes I did and it's straight to ground too, no resistance

Comment: Check that the ‘reset’ circuit is working with an oscilloscope in the bottom left of the schematic.